# Functions calls caller for no apparent reason

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

I'm using glut to make a simple game. The glut display callback looks like this:

```
std::chrono::duration<float> timeDelta = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - lastFrame;
lastFrame = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::cout << (1 / timeDelta.count()) << "fps" << std::endl; // print fps

game->draw();

std::cout << "finished frame"  << std::endl << std::endl;

glutSwapBuffers();
```

For some reason the function never finishes and the console output looks like this:

```
166.639fps
draw game
166.667fps
draw game
```

repeating infinitely.

The `draw` function looks like this:

```
std::cout << "draw game" << std::endl;
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
glClearColor(RENDER_BRIGHTNESS, RENDER_BRIGHTNESS, RENDER_BRIGHTNESS, 1);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

camera.draw();
world.draw();

//Bind 0, which means render to back buffer
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1, 1);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, frameTexture);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor4d(1, 1, 1, 1);
    glTexCoord2d(0, 0); glVertex2d(0, 0);
    glTexCoord2d(1, 0); glVertex2d(width, 0);
    glTexCoord2d(1, 1); glVertex2d(width, height);
    glTexCoord2d(0, 1); glVertex2d(0, height);
glEnd();
```

`camera.draw()` simply manipulates gls matrices. The `world.draw()` function iterates over the nodes of an octree (using this implementation: http://nomis80.org/code/octree.html) using frustum culling (copied from here: http://www.crownandcutlass.com/features/technicaldetails/frustum.html) and draws the leaves as cubes.

`draw game` is printed by the `game->draw()` function. `finished frame` is never printed. It looks like the `game->draw()` function calls the display function recursively even though it's in a different file and doesn't have a pointer to it. Is it even possible to archive this effect with code? Is that a bug in mingw-g++?

The octree often uses the unsafe function reinterpret_cast. Could this be the source of the problem?

I hope it's not necessary to post the complete source-code as it is quite huge.

Comment: Let's see the `draw` function (at least trimmed down to still reproduce the behaviour).

Comment: Looks like recursive calls (either direct or indirect recursive). Or callstack corruption.

Comment: I added some more information to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a helpful article about debugging a callstack corruption http://hisham.hm/2012/02/14/debugging-a-stack-corruption-with-gdb/
Turns out dereferencing a dangling pointer caused the problem.